# System.Drawing.Image.FromFile wpf pack uri's?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm running into an issue with trying to use the "FromFile" call from the System.Drawing.Image.FromFile namespace, more specifically It doesn't seem to support URI's or WPF's  pack paths ( pack://application:,,,/ ), thus I can't figure out how to properly assign the image path. A little help or direction would be appreciated, as this has stumped me for the past few hours and I don't want to end up hard-coding a path.

Comment: Your question is unclear and too broad. `FromFile()` method is going to require an actual _file_, which is not what an embedded resource is, and what `pack:` is used for. There is good documentation on MSDN, as well as plentiful information on Stack Overflow regarding how to access resource data in WPF using the `pack:` URI scheme. First, figure out what it is you actually want to do, then research. Then try. If you still have trouble after all of that, post a question with a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces whatever problem it is you're having.

Comment: I'm aware of how the pack system works. Here are some more details. I'm currently using BitmapImage's and I can assign the path like so : new Uri("pack://application:,,,/app;component/Images/image.png");. The problem is that I have to switch to a different implementation to produce the results I want. I switched my implementation to use System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("xx\\xx\\image.png"). The fromfile() does not support uri's or pack:// urls, thus forcing me to drop all the .pngs into a folder. I'd like to not have them in a folder when i deploy my solution, as i currently have it set that way.

Comment: If you are required to use `FromFile()`, then you have to use files. If you can switch to [`FromStream()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx), then you can retrieve your embedded resource as a stream and instantiate the `Image` object that way. Why you are mixing GDI+ `Image` objects with WPF, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `Image` control and its `Source` property.
2. You can use `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` class and its constructor or `UriSource` property.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem. read my response above, I went further into detail.